# History of the probe request?

Tags: wireless, ip, packet-analysis, access-point

I'm interested in the individual history of the probe request specifically - when and where the agreements were made for the protocol to function as it does today.  Anyone have any good history lessons to share?

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to look at the minutes and reports from the IEEE 802.11 working group sessions [at the IEEE website.](http://www.ieee802.org/11/Reports) I think they also keep the detailed proposals for all features online, you should be able to find even more details if required.